# Property Binding the List property on an input in Angular

Tags: angular

```
<input [list]="foo + 'name'"/>
<input list={{foo + 'name'}}/>
```

**foo**

```
public foo : number = 3;
```

In essence I want to create dynamic lists bound to dynamic inputs. The error I am coming up against is

> Cannot set property list of [object HTMLInputElement] which has only a getter

Which is cool I understand, the property **list** on an input element doesnt have a setter, it only has a getter. How can I get around this. I want to create a dynamic input that is bound to a dynamic datalist element (at run time)

Comment: does attribute binding work for you? `<input [attr.list]=""/>` https://angular.io/guide/attribute-binding#binding-to-an-attribute

Comment: I tried your scenario with [attr.list] property. Here is the example of your scenario https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zxcihd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: @BizzyBob   thank you very much. Both your answers are correct and they worked for me. If you make you answers into question i will upvote and check bizzybob (because he was first)

Comment: @Muthupriya if you make your comment into an answer I will upvote it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [attribute binding](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-binding#binding-to-an-attribute).  Assuming you have a controller property called `theList` that's set to either `list-a` or `list-b`, you can change it dynamically like this:

example:

```
<button (click)="toggleList()">Toggle List</button>

<input [attr.list]="theList" />

<datalist id="list-a">
    <option value="A-1">
    <option value="A-2">
    <option value="A-3">
</datalist>

<datalist id="list-b">
    <option value="B-1">
    <option value="B-2">
    <option value="B-3">
</datalist>
```

Here is a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-66069237?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: `[attr.list]` was key. Thank you! This was the ONLY result from google for my error message, and this answer is the golden ticket :-)

Answer (score 1):

For attribute binding, you have to prefix it with `attr`. So your HTML would need to change to this:

```
<input [arr.list]="foo + 'name'"/>
```

Docs: https://angular.io/guide/attribute-binding#syntax